# Android - TextView inside a ConstraintLayout goes off to infinity to the right - how to pin with ImageView and have ellipsis too

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to make my `TextView` has a dynamic width and an `ImageView` pinned to the end of it, inside of a `ConstraintLayout`. When the text is very long, I want to use an ellipsis and have the `ImageView` pin to the view to the right of it.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve visually:

[image]

[image]

With my code, I am able to achieve the first image with `thisIsShortText` but when I have long text, it looks **bad**, like this:

[image]

[image]

The `TextView` and `ImageView` just go off to the right to infinity. Can anyone help me fix this? This is the XML code I have. If you just put it into your Android Studio it will look like my images. Thank you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

    <!-- This view does not move or change size. -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </View>

    <!-- This view's width is dynamic and changes size based on it's text length.
     If the length of text is too long to fit, it uses an ellipsize. -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="thisIsVeryLongTextThatIsTooLongAndIsLong"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_dark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/firstView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- This view is pinned to the end of textView. -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- This view does not move or change size. -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/thirdView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- This view does not move or change size. -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/thirdView"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding the below to the `TextView`:

- Enabling width constraints.
- Using a packed chain with a 0 horizontal bias.
- Constraint the end to the start of the right view (`imageview`)

And constraint the end of the info `imageview` to the start of the `secondView`

So, you need to add the following to the `textview`:

```
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/secondView"
```

And to the `imageview`:

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/secondView"
```

Now the entire layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

    <!-- This view does not move or change size. -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </View>

    <!-- This view's width is dynamic and changes size based on it's text length.
     If the length of text is too long to fit, it uses an ellipsize. -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="thisIsVeryLongTextThatIsTooLongAndIsLong"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text_dark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageview"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/firstView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- This view is pinned to the end of textView. -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/secondView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- This view does not move or change size. -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/thirdView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- This view does not move or change size. -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/thirdView"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! The `layout_constrainedWidth` really saved the day. What does it do exactly?

Comment: @BlueBoy Welcome.. `layout_constrainedWidth` is used whenever you have a `wrap_content` width and want to enforce constraints whenever there is a conflict between the `wrap_content` & the width constraints.. In other words.. apply wrap_content until the constraints is met, once constraints are violated, stick to the constraints. Check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#wrap_content-:-enforcing-constraints-added-in-1.1) for more info